# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target_id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I see a similar question has been asked elsewhere. I'm going to ask anyway.

In my react component I have the following:

```
    let n = extract_vals(this.props.post);
    return (
      <div key={this.props.post.nid} className="post">
        {n.field_image}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In this case n.field_image is an Object so it will error:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {target_id, alt, title, width, height, target_type, target_uuid, url}).`

But note that there is an object key "target_id". However when I do the following:

```
    let n = extract_vals(this.props.post);
    return (
      <div key={this.props.post.nid} className="post">
        {n.field_image.target_id}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target_id' of undefined
```

It's a catch 22! How is this happening? The object IS defined!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It seems it was a situation where I had an unresolved promise and render was happening before and after the state was being updated.